# Drum machine options for worship team (non-drummer)

Tags: drums, drum-machine, drum-hardware

Our worship team is in need of a mechanical option for a drummer. I have looked at several options but, as a non-drummer, I don't know which of those options would be a good match for our needs. As a non-drummer, much of the language used in the product descriptions is lost on me. I've looked at the Alesis SR-16 & 18, the Korg Volca, the Roland T-8 and several others.

Here are the things we need to consider when looking at our options:

1. **We need something that a non-drummer could use.** Something easy to learn and use.
2. I am a vocalist, not a musician. I count on the drums to keep the tempo; the drums cannot count on me for that. In other words, me trying to learn to play the actual drums and keep the tempo for the team would be a scary thing. **We need something that can provide at least the basic beats/rhythms to start** until I can learn to do more with the machine. (Are there press and play options? Something that can play pre-recorded beats I can start and stop at the beginning and end of the song, with the option to do more as I learn.)
3. It would probably need to be a **physical piece of hardware** rather than software. I will need to operate it from the platform while singing.
4. We will need to be able to **connect** it to our **sound system**.
5. We would like to stay under the $300.00 range if possible.

Comment: Welcome, and sorry, but gear recommendation is not on the menu here, so this will soon get closed. I shouldn't, but I'm just going to suggest something different - Beat Buddy. That's all!

Comment: You need to ask yourself what you want *musically*. If the only purpose is to keep a steady beat, I'd probably simply prepare a track that I hit "play" on. I've been on teams that have a laptop in the drum cage, and the live drummer handles hitting play and stop on a "loop" that provides some atmospheric fills or synth patterns, and has a second "click track" that routes only to the team's in-ear monitors. This investment might also be the most flexible for other uses. But if you want a certain 80s or 90s drum-machine aesthetic, then that might affect your choice.

Comment: If product recommendations were allowed here, I would second @Tim's suggestion of Beat Buddy.  I have one since the original Kickstarter.  It's a bit of a pain to customize but doesn't require programming of a whole song.

Comment: Look for (old) keyboards, e.g. from Yamaha. Those providing a rhythm section may also have an intro and outro button. However, they usually suit other genres. And you must like the inflexibility that comes with it. I.e. as a drummer I listen to the others and adjust as needed. My bands liked that.

Comment: Although product recommendations are off topic, questions about the language in product descriptions would be very much on topic.